# Call to GetModuleHandle on kernel32 using Python C-types

Tags: python, ctypes, python-3.2

I'm trying to use Python's C-Types to call GetModuleHandleA on the kernel32 library.  I'd like to get a handle to the library so I can use it to call GetProcAddress for LoadLibraryA.  Below is my code...

```
import sys
from ctypes

kernel32 = windll.kernel32
print("The kernel32 is %s" % kernel32)
#The kernel32 is <WinDLL 'kernel32', handle 765b0000 at 1c2a9f0>

h_kernel32 = kernel32.GetModuleHandleA("C:\\Windows\\System32\\kernel32.dll")
if h_kernel32 == False:
        error = GetLastError()
        print("ERROR: %d - %s" % (error, FormatError(error)))
```

I'm getting an error, "ERROR: 126 - The specified module could not be found".  I've also tried "C:/Windows/System32/kernel32.dll" and just "kernel32".  I'm using Python 3.2 and this is on a Windows 7 machine.  I've verified that the dll is there and in the path that I have set in the code above.  I've been doing some research and can't seem to find out what the issue is.  Any help is greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The handle is stored in `kernel32._handle`. Calling `GetModuleHandle` should return the same value, but make sure you set `restype` and `argtypes` for type safety [*]:

```
import ctypes
from ctypes import wintypes

kernel32 = ctypes.WinDLL('kernel32', use_last_error=True)

kernel32.GetModuleHandleW.restype = wintypes.HMODULE
kernel32.GetModuleHandleW.argtypes = [wintypes.LPCWSTR]

hMod = kernel32.GetModuleHandleW('kernel32.dll')
```

Notice the 'W' suffix instead of 'A'. Python 3 uses Unicode strings, for which ctypes creates a `c_wchar_p` (`LPCWSTR`). There's no reason to call the [A]NSI version since it's just a wrapper around the [W]ide string version. But if you must, then you need to use bytes:

```
kernel32.GetModuleHandleA.restype = wintypes.HMODULE
kernel32.GetModuleHandleA.argtypes = [wintypes.LPCSTR]

hMod = kernel32.GetModuleHandleA(b'kernel32.dll')
```

---

[*] I recommend using `kernel32 = WinDLL('kernel32', use_last_error=True)` instead of `windll.kernel32`. This avoids conflicts with other modules that use `windll`. It also enables protection for the thread's `LastErrorValue`. In this case, use `ctypes.get_last_error()` and `ctypes.set_last_error(err)` instead of directly calling WinAPI `GetLastError` and `SetLastError`.

Answer (score 0):

As for how it's done internally, `ctypes.windll.kernel32` is `WinDLL("kernel32")`. WinDLL inherits CDLL, whose `__init__` opens a handle to kernel32.dll using `self._handle = ctypes._dlopen` (`from _ctypes import LoadLibrary as _dlopen`), and `LoadLibrary` is bound to the `load_library` C function in the runtime, which calls `LoadLibraryExW`, and then returns a call to `PyLong_FromVoidPtr`, which creates a `PyObject` (`PyLong`) from a C void pointer (`HMODULE`) and returns it, and just like a regular function implemented in python, it now internally has a `PyObject` that it uses to assign to `self._handke`). The CDLL `__getattr__` is called by the runtime the first time `"GetModuleHandle"` is used on `kernel32`, and this python code instantiates an object of `_FuncPtr` type for it, which inherits `_CFuncPtr`, which is a `_ctypes.CFuncPtr` (`from _ctypes import _CFuncPtr as CFuncPtr`).

The type identifier `_ctypes.CFuncPtr` is bound to a C object (`PyCFuncPtr_Type` of type `PyTypeObject`) in the definition of said C object in the runtime library; the identifier string is a member of the object. Remember that under the hood the runtime creates `PyObject`s for all python objects (including python functions), and a `PyTypeObject` for all python types, this is usually done implicitly by the runtime but in this case the python code explicitly creates a function object that can be used to make the native call. It now uses the constructor `PyCFuncPtr_new` set in the type object (`PyCFuncPtr_Type`) in C to instantiate the actual function object from the function type object, which takes the args, in this case the kernel32 WinDLL object and `"GetModuleHandle"`, and calls `PyCFuncPtr_FromDll` (because the very fact there are arguments means it's not a regular function) to create a new function object and associate it with the actual function address using `GetProcAddress` on the handle to the module in WinDLL set up in the CDLL `__init__`.

A call performed on this function object will cause python to call the address in this object, which will be `GetProcAddress` instead of an address of a function that interprets the bytecode at the bytecode address... I assume.

Next time the `__getattr__` is not called because the attribute now exists.