# GetModuleHandleA fails to get modules not used by python.exe when attached to another process

Tags: python, code-injection, ctypes, kernel32

I am working with Grey Hat Python book at the moment. It describes on how to create a debugger in python. So far my debugger is able to start the process and attach to it. The problem happens when I try to retrieve a module handle from the process. According to OllyDbg the DLL is present in the program, but `GetModuleHandleA` fails to get a handle. I improved a code from the book a little bit so in case `GetModuleHandleA` fails to retrieve a handle the function will try to create a remote thread and force to load this module into the process. But even so it `GetModuleHandleA` fails (while everything else works fine). So maybe someone can take a quick glance at the code and see the problem in it?

```
def func_resolve(self,dll,function):
    handle  = kernel32.GetModuleHandleA(dll)
    print "%s module handle is at 0x%08x" % (dll, handle)
    error = kernel32.GetLastError()
    if error:
        print "There was an error in func_resolve::GetModuleHandleA(%s): %d" % (dll, error)
        print "Loading library into the process"
        pLibRemote = kernel32.VirtualAllocEx(self.h_process, 0, len(dll), 0x00001000, 0x04)
        print "Allocated %d bytes of memory at 0x%08x" % (len(dll), pLibRemote)
        written = c_int(0)
        kernel32.WriteProcessMemory(self.h_process, pLibRemote, dll, len(dll), byref(written))
        print "Written %d bytes" % written.value
        handle  = kernel32.GetModuleHandleA("kernel32.dll")
        print "Kernel module handle is 0x%08x" % handle
        address = kernel32.GetProcAddress(handle, "LoadLibraryA")
        print "LoadLibraryA address is 0x%08x" % address
        thread_id = c_ulong(0)
        kernel32.CreateRemoteThread(self.h_process, None, 0, address, pLibRemote, 0, byref(thread_id))
        print "Created thread %d" % thread_id.value
    handle  = kernel32.GetModuleHandleA(dll)
    address = kernel32.GetProcAddress(handle, function)
    kernel32.CloseHandle(handle)
    return address
```

The output looks like this:

```
[*] We have successfully launched the process!
[*] The Process ID I have is: 10380
Proces handle is 228
opengl32.dll module handle is at 0x00000000
There was an error in func_resolve::GetModuleHandleA(opengl32.dll): 126
Loading library into the process
Allocated 12 bytes of memory at 0x002c0000
Written 12 bytes
Kernel module handle is 0x772c0000
LoadLibraryA address is 0x772d498f
Created thread 11136
[*] Address of func: 0x00000000
[*] Setting breakpoint at: 0x00000000
```

The module handle is retrieved fine if it is used by python.exe (is among the imported list of python.exe process). But modules that are not in python.exe processes fail. Maybe that could be related somehow to OS Windows 7 (64 bit), but still application that I test against was compiled with a 32 bit compiler.

Update 2: According to recommendation in comments I wrote my own function:

```
def my_func_resolve(self, dll, function):
    module32 = MODULEENTRY32()
    CreateToolhelp32Snapshot = kernel32.CreateToolhelp32Snapshot
    CreateToolhelp32Snapshot.restype = HANDLE
    CreateToolhelp32Snapshot.argtypes = [DWORD, DWORD]
    Module32First = kernel32.Module32First
    Module32First.restype = BOOL
    Module32First.argtypes = [HANDLE, POINTER(MODULEENTRY32)]
    Module32Next = kernel32.Module32Next
    Module32Next.restype = BOOL
    Module32Next.argtypes = [HANDLE, POINTER(MODULEENTRY32)]
    thandle = 24
    while thandle == 24:
        thandle = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPMODULE, self.pid)
    if thandle == 0 or thandle == 0xFFFFFFFF:
        print "Failed to create a snapshot. Error: %d" % kernel32.GetLastError()
        exit()
    if not Module32First(thandle, byref(module32)):
        print "Module32First failed. Error: %d" % kernel32.GetLastError()
        kernel32.CloseHandle(thandle)
        exit()
    while module32:
        print "DLL %s is loaded at 0x%08x" % (module32.szModule, module32.modBaseAddr)
        Module32Next(thandle, byref(module32))
    kernel32.CloseHandle(thandle)
    return True
```

but it fails with

```
[*] We have successfully launched the process!
[*] The Process ID I have is: 9584
Proces handle is 228
Failed create snapshot. Error: 299
```

Which is ERROR_PARTIAL_COPY and happens if we are trying to retrieve 64 bit process from 32 bit process. I have 32 bit python. My OS is 64 bit. I compiled testprog.exe using mingw 32 bit compiler. How that happened that I get this error now?
For `TH32CS_SNAPMODULE` I used both `0x00000008` and `0x00000010`

Just in case, the process is created in this way:

```
if kernel32.CreateProcessA(path_to_exe,
                            None,
                            None,
                            None,
                            None,
                            creation_flags,
                            None,
                            None,
                            byref(startupinfo),
                            byref(process_information)):
    print "[*] We have successfully launched the process!"
    print "[*] The Process ID I have is: %d" % \
                    process_information.dwProcessId
    self.pid = process_information.dwProcessId
    self.h_process = self.open_process(process_information.dwProcessId)
    print "Proces handle is %d" % self.h_process
```

Comment: `GetModuleHandle` looks for the module in the current process. To find a module in another process you need to use the PSAPI  functions `EnumProcessModulesEx` & `GetModuleBaseName` or the Tool Help API functions `CreateToolhelp32Snapshot`, `Module32First`, & `Module32Next`.

Comment: Note that `HMODULE` handles are pointers, so you'll need to set the `restype` and `argtypes` of all functions that use them to prevent truncating 64-bit pointer values as a 32-bit C `int` values.

Comment: I forgot to mention that you also need to load the DLL into your current process using `LoadLibraryEx` with `DONT_RESOLVE_DLL_REFERENCES`, and use this `HMODULE` when calling `GetProcAddress`. Then adjust the function address according to the DLL `HMODULE` (base address) in the target process.

Comment: Looks like this is the answer ) Thanks @eryksun ! You'd could post all that as an answer to the question )

Comment: You never call `CreateToolhelp32Snapshot` because of the weird loop test `while thandle == 24`.

Comment: Oh, sh..t. Missed that moment. 24 is ERROR_BAD_LENGTH code. MSDN states if it happens - try once again.

Comment: If `CreateToolhelp32Snapshot` fails, it returns `INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE`. Define that as `INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE = wintypes.HANDLE(-1).value`. Initialize `thandle = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE`.

Comment: All of the cases where you call `GetLastError` should be handled differently. Outside of the method, at class or module level, define `kernel32 = ctypes.WinDLL('kernel32', use_last_error=True)` and the function prototypes (define them only once). If a function fails raise an exception via `raise ctypes.WinError(ctypes.get_last_error())`. Do everything in a `try` / `finally`. In the `finally` block if `thandle != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE` then `kernel32.CloseHandle(thandle)`.

Comment: Thanks @eryksun ! I don't worry much about the code standards now so this is just an educational task for myself. That is why I deal with defines and exceptions in so dirty way within this functions. I use GetLastError only for debugging.

Comment: I've just updated the my_func_resolve part and now I am getting ERROR_PARTIAL_COPY. It happens if we are trying to retrieve 64 bit process from 32 bit process. I have 32 bit python, 64 bit OS and testprog.exe compiled using mingw 32 bit compiler, so it should be 32 bit as well. Why that error happens?

Comment: I also added check `kernel32.IsWow64Process(self.h_process, byref(is64))` and it says that process is really 64 bit. Maybe it has to do something with CreateProcess function to force it to create 32 bit process with 32 bit executable?

Comment: Tried this code with 64 bit python. CreateToolhelp32Snapshot returns error handle: 0xFFFFF..FF with the same error 299, which is ERROR_PARTIAL_COPY

Comment: The trick with getting the address delta between the current process and the target process only works for the same CPU word size, i.e. the debugger and the target need to both be either 32-bit or 64-bit. You shouldn't need `TH32CS_SNAPMODULE32`.

Comment: As to `IsWow64Process`, the `Wow64Process` output parameter is true for a 32-bit process. WOW64 is short for Win32 running on Win64 (i.e. the environment used to run 32-bit programs in 64-bit Windows). Even a 32-bit WOW64 process has some 64-bit modules, such as ntdll.dll, wow64.dll, wow64win.dll, and wow64cpu.dll.

Comment: I made sure that testprog.exe is truly 32 bit executable. Also I am running 32 bit python (sys.maxsize > 2**32 == False). So the CPU word size should be the same, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`GetModuleHandle` looks for a module in the current process. To find a module in another process you need to use the PSAPI functions `EnumProcessModulesEx` & `GetModuleBaseName` or the Tool Help functions `CreateToolhelp32Snapshot`, `Module32First`, & `Module32Next`.

If the target process has the same architecture as the current process, then you can indirectly find procedure addresses in its loaded DLLs. First, load the DLL in the current process via `LoadLibraryEx` with `DONT_RESOLVE_DLL_REFERENCES`. Then call `GetProcAddress` with this local `HMODULE` to get the local address. Finally, adjust the local address relative to the module base address in the target process. Remember to call `FreeLibrary` to unload the DLL from the current process.

Note that `HMODULE` handles are actually pointers, so you'll need to set `restype` and `argtypes` for all ctypes functions. This prevents truncating 64-bit pointer values as 32-bit C `int` values.

Here's an example using the Tool Help functions.

```
import os
import ctypes
from ctypes import wintypes

kernel32 = ctypes.WinDLL('kernel32', use_last_error=True)
wintypes.LPBOOL = ctypes.POINTER(wintypes.BOOL)

ERROR_NO_MORE_FILES = 0x0012
ERROR_BAD_LENGTH    = 0x0018
ERROR_MOD_NOT_FOUND = 0x007E

INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE = wintypes.HANDLE(-1).value
DONT_RESOLVE_DLL_REFERENCES = 0x00000001
MAX_PATH = 260
MAX_MODULE_NAME32 = 255
TH32CS_SNAPMODULE   = 0x00000008

class MODULEENTRY32W(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = (('dwSize',        wintypes.DWORD),
                ('th32ModuleID',  wintypes.DWORD),
                ('th32ProcessID', wintypes.DWORD),
                ('GlblcntUsage',  wintypes.DWORD),
                ('ProccntUsage',  wintypes.DWORD),
                ('modBaseAddr',   wintypes.LPVOID),
                ('modBaseSize',   wintypes.DWORD),
                ('hModule',       wintypes.HMODULE),
                ('szModule',      wintypes.WCHAR * (MAX_MODULE_NAME32 + 1)),
                ('szExePath',     wintypes.WCHAR * MAX_PATH))
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwds):
        super(MODULEENTRY32W, self).__init__(*args, **kwds)
        self.dwSize = ctypes.sizeof(self)

LPMODULEENTRY32W = ctypes.POINTER(MODULEENTRY32W)

def errcheck_bool(result, func, args):
    if not result:
        raise ctypes.WinError(ctypes.get_last_error())
    return args

def errcheck_ihv(result, func, args):
    if result == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE:
        raise ctypes.WinError(ctypes.get_last_error())
    return args

kernel32.LoadLibraryExW.errcheck = errcheck_bool
kernel32.LoadLibraryExW.restype = wintypes.HMODULE
kernel32.LoadLibraryExW.argtypes = (wintypes.LPCWSTR,
                                    wintypes.HANDLE,
                                    wintypes.DWORD)

kernel32.FreeLibrary.errcheck = errcheck_bool
kernel32.FreeLibrary.argtypes = (wintypes.HMODULE,)

kernel32.GetProcAddress.errcheck = errcheck_bool
kernel32.GetProcAddress.restype = wintypes.LPVOID
kernel32.GetProcAddress.argtypes = (wintypes.HMODULE,
                                    wintypes.LPCSTR)

kernel32.CloseHandle.errcheck = errcheck_bool
kernel32.CloseHandle.argtypes = (wintypes.HANDLE,)

kernel32.CreateToolhelp32Snapshot.errcheck = errcheck_ihv
kernel32.CreateToolhelp32Snapshot.restype = wintypes.HANDLE
kernel32.CreateToolhelp32Snapshot.argtypes = (wintypes.DWORD,
                                              wintypes.DWORD)

kernel32.Module32FirstW.errcheck = errcheck_bool
kernel32.Module32FirstW.argtypes = (wintypes.HANDLE,
                                    LPMODULEENTRY32W)

kernel32.Module32NextW.errcheck = errcheck_bool
kernel32.Module32NextW.argtypes = (wintypes.HANDLE,
                                   LPMODULEENTRY32W)

def GetRemoteProcAddress(pid, filename, procname):
    procname = procname.encode('utf-8')
    hLocal = kernel32.LoadLibraryExW(filename, None,
                                     DONT_RESOLVE_DLL_REFERENCES)
    try:
        procaddr = kernel32.GetProcAddress(hLocal, procname)
    finally:
        kernel32.FreeLibrary(hLocal)
    modname = os.path.basename(filename)
    hRemote = GetRemoteModuleHandle(pid, modname)
    return hRemote - hLocal + procaddr

def GetRemoteModuleHandle(pid, modname):
    modname = modname.upper()
    if '.' not in modname:
        modname += '.DLL'
    while True:
        try:
            hProcessSnap = kernel32.CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(
                                TH32CS_SNAPMODULE, pid)
            break
        except OSError as e:
            if e.winerror != ERROR_BAD_LENGTH:
                raise
    try:
        modentry = MODULEENTRY32W()
        kernel32.Module32FirstW(hProcessSnap,
                                ctypes.byref(modentry))
        while True:
            if modentry.szModule.upper() == modname:
                return modentry.hModule
            try:
                kernel32.Module32NextW(hProcessSnap,
                                       ctypes.byref(modentry))
            except OSError as e:
                if e.winerror == ERROR_NO_MORE_FILES:
                    break
                raise
        raise ctypes.WinError(ERROR_MOD_NOT_FOUND)
    finally:
        kernel32.CloseHandle(hProcessSnap)
```

Here's a test that creates another Python process and verifies that kernel32.dll is loaded at the same address as the current process; that `LoadLibraryExW` is resolved at the same address; and that the first 1000 bytes are equal.

Note that I use a Windows Event object to wait for the child process to finish loading before attempting to read its module table. This avoids the problem with `ERROR_PARTIAL_COPY`. If the target is a GUI process with a message queue, you can instead use [`WaitForInputIdle`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms687022).

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    import subprocess

    if len(sys.argv) > 1:
        # child process
        import time
        hEvent = int(sys.argv[1])
        kernel32.SetEvent(hEvent)
        time.sleep(120)
        sys.exit(0)

    wintypes.SIZE_T = ctypes.c_size_t
    kernel32.ReadProcessMemory.argtypes = (wintypes.HANDLE,
                                           wintypes.LPVOID,
                                           wintypes.LPVOID,
                                           wintypes.SIZE_T,
                                           ctypes.POINTER(wintypes.SIZE_T))

    class SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES(ctypes.Structure):
        _fields_ = (('nLength',              wintypes.DWORD),
                    ('lpSecurityDescriptor', wintypes.LPVOID),
                    ('bInheritHandle',       wintypes.BOOL))
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwds):
        super(SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES, self).__init__(*args, **kwds)
        self.nLength = ctypes.sizeof(self)

    WAIT_OBJECT_0 = 0
    CREATE_NO_WINDOW = 0x08000000

    sa = SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES(bInheritHandle=True)
    hEvent = kernel32.CreateEventW(ctypes.byref(sa), 0, 0, None)
    script = os.path.abspath(__file__)
    p = subprocess.Popen([sys.executable, script, str(hEvent)],
                         close_fds=False,
                         creationflags=CREATE_NO_WINDOW)
    try:
        result = kernel32.WaitForSingleObject(hEvent, 60 * 1000)
        if result != WAIT_OBJECT_0:
            sys.exit('wait failed')
        # kernel32 should load at the same address in a given session.
        hModule = GetRemoteModuleHandle(p.pid, 'kernel32')
        assert hModule == kernel32._handle
        remote_addr = GetRemoteProcAddress(p.pid,
                                           'kernel32',
                                           'LoadLibraryExW')
        local_addr = ctypes.c_void_p.from_buffer(
                        kernel32.LoadLibraryExW).value
        assert remote_addr == local_addr
        remote_bytes = (ctypes.c_char * 1000)()
        read = wintypes.SIZE_T()
        kernel32.ReadProcessMemory(int(p._handle),
                                   remote_addr,
                                   remote_bytes, 1000,
                                   ctypes.byref(read))
        local_bytes = ctypes.string_at(kernel32.LoadLibraryExW, 1000)
        assert remote_bytes[:] == local_bytes
    finally:
        p.terminate()
```

Comment: It looks like I messed up with CreateProcessA function. If I use Popen subprocess in my code, it works. If I use your functions in my code with old CreateProcessA - it fails with the same error. So there is a problem with access to the process. Anyway, you help was super useful, now I know where to look at. Thanks!

Comment: It's not obvious what the problem is with `CreateProcess`. Maybe if you show how you've defined the structures and `argtypes` and what the value of `creation_flags` is. I can say that `self.h_process = self.open_process(process_information.dwProcessId)` is unnecessary. You already have an all-access handle as `process_information.hProcess`.

Comment: `CreateProcessA` had only path to exe, creation_flags equal to `DEBUG_PROCESS` and references to instances of `STARTUPINFO` and `PROCESS_INFORMATION`. `startupinfo.dwFlags = 0x1; startupinfo.wShowWindow = 0x0; startupinfo.cb = sizeof(startupinfo);` Then `kernel32.OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS,False,pid)` was called. Actually all the defines can be found here https://www.nostarch.com/download/ghpython_src.zip  inside the my_debugger_defines.py file

Comment: I had the problem with `ERROR_PARTIAL_COPY` when I tried to read from the child process too soon, before the loader startup code had actually built the module table. That's why I added the event object for the child to set once it's fully loaded. If you can't do something like that, trying adding a 2 second delay via `time.sleep(2)` right after calling `CreateProcess`.

Comment: Well I am adding 5 seconds which is more then enough for my test program but that still not a rescue at the moment.

Comment: Is your test program waiting? I haven't experimented with trying to read the module table of a process that already exited or is in the process of exiting.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99807/discussion-between-artur-korobeynyk-and-eryksun).

Comment: I found the reason of my fails. I was creating process with the DEBUG_PROCESS flag and it suspended the process as soon as there any debugging event occurred. So you would need to call the ContinueDebugEvent method to resume the main thread until the next debug event. Without any flags code works fine. I captured those only when rewrote my code in C++ and debugged that =)

Comment: The loader can't build the module table if it's suspended. ;-)

Comment: Yeap, so this is completely solved now. Thanks for assistance! )

Comment: `if e.winerror != ERROR_BAD_LENGTH` you think that *If the function fails with `ERROR_BAD_LENGTH`, retry the function until it succeeds.* - can be true but not documentation bug (how i personally sure) ? how this is can be possible at all if take to account that `CreateToolhelp32Snapshot` not take any buffer size value or even any data which let determinate are this first or retry call.

Comment: @RbMm, `CreateToolhelp32Snapshot` calls `ThpCreateRawSnap` -> `RtlQueryProcessDebugInformation` -> `RtlQueryProcessModuleInformation`. The latter calls `LdrQueryProcessModuleInformationEx` twice, the first time to get the buffer size for the module list. If the size changes in between, the second call can fail with `STATUS_INFO_LENGTH_MISMATCH`. I forced this case under a debugger, and the status code was propagated back up to the top and converted to WinAPI `ERROR_BAD_LENGTH`. So I do think this can happen, but it's a rare race condition.

Comment: yes, you correct. strange that not note this yourself. anyway think this is bad api design. how and current solution with read loader list from remote process. i yourself not use this api, and prefer own solution, more close to old `RtlQueryProcessDebugInformation` implementation

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation on [System Error Codes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681382(v=vs.85).aspx), error code 126 is `ERROR_MOD_NOT_FOUND`.  You might want to review the [DLL Search Path](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7d83bc18.aspx) to make sure the DLL is installed in the right place.  opengl32.dll is pretty common though, so I'd expect this to be available.

Another possibility could be that your code is calling `GetModuleHandleA` (the Windows code page or "ANSI" version of the function), but passing wide character Unicode strings.  `GetModuleHandleA` would not be able to interpret Unicode strings properly, so it would search for the wrong module.  If this were the case, then the fix would be to change your code to call `GetModuleHandleW`.  Python 3 in particular uses Unicode for strings, so if you're running with Python 3, then this is likely to be relevant.

The [Unicode in the Windows API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd374089(v=vs.85).aspx) documentation has more discussion of the `A` vs. `W` naming convention for functions and the distinction between functions capable of handling Windows code pages and functions capable of handling Unicode.

This previous question looks similar.

[Call to GetModuleHandle on kernel32 using Python C-types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17033733/call-to-getmodulehandle-on-kernel32-using-python-c-types)

Comment: All the mentioned cases are not relevant to me but might help other people with the same problem so I upped it. I've already seen posts that had similar problems and verified that Unicode and dll path is not a reason of my case. I tried several different dlls from system path, also my own dll that was used to link the executable binary test file and result is always the same - GetModuleHandleA fails. Also I use Python 2.7 so ANSI standard suits me. And previous post looks like related to Python 3 Unicode problem.