# DLL Injection - CreateRemoteThread

Tags: python, windows, security, dll, dll-injection

Hello again at StackOverflow!

I return for help on implementing DLL injection using Python, and the results have been fairly successful. I am using non-reflective injection (`'CreateRemoteThread'`) to inject 'Python27.dll' into a process. This has been successful. **My problem comes when trying to access functions within the injected DLL.**

Namely: `'Py_InitializeEx'` and 
`'PyRun_SimpleString'` functions (Initializes interpreter, allows a simple string to be passed to interpreter).

This will be a rather involved explanation, apologies in advance.

The first VM I have tested the code on is a x86-XP machine, when `'Py_InitializeEx'`'' is called, the OS returns an error(OS MessageBox) to the effect of "Data Execution Prevention" , "To help protect your computer, Windows has closed this program". So i simply turned of DEP, however even after reboots, the error persists.

I migrated testing over to x64-Win7 (namely for DEP list in tskmgr.exe :P), and attacked non DEP enabled processes. Windows just shuts down the victim processes. I reckon for the same reason, just for 'security' purposes, MSoft probably removed the DEP warning.

This leads me to think that i must definitley must be doing something wrong, as i have seen examples of similar functionality within Python code. My question is, simply, **can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?**

Thanks in advance :)

```
kernel32 = windll.kernel32
PAGE_READWRITE = 0x04 #Set token values
PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS = ( 0x00F0000 | 0x00100000 | 0xFFF )
VIRTUAL_MEM = ( 0x1000 | 0x2000 )

dllpath = r"C:\Documents and Settings\isolina\desktop\python27.dll"
dlllen = len(dllpath)#Set program variable
pid = 8972

processh = kernel32.OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, False, int(pid))#Attach to process by gaining a handle
dllpathaddr = kernel32.VirtualAllocEx(processh, 0, dlllen, VIRTUAL_MEM, PAGE_READWRITE)#Allocate room within the processes memory for the code
NULL = c_int(0)
kernel32.WriteProcessMemory(processh, dllpathaddr, dllpath, dlllen, NULL)#Write DLL path to process memory

kernel32h = kernel32.GetModuleHandleA("kernel32.dll")
loadlibh = kernel32.GetProcAddress(kernel32h, "LoadLibraryA")#Get address off LoadLibraryA function
thread_id = c_ulong(0)
if not kernel32.CreateRemoteThread(processh, None, 0, loadlibh, dllpathaddr, 0, byref(thread_id)):#Execute LoadLibraryA on DLL path in target process
    print "Check yo' privileges, bro!"
    exit()
print "Remote Thread: 0x%08x" %(thread_id.value)

pyhand = kernel32.GetModuleHandleA("python27.dll")
py_initialize_ex = thread_id.value + (kernel32.GetProcAddress(pyhand, 'Py_InitializeEx') - pyhand)
pyrun_simple_string = thread_id.value + (kernel32.GetProcAddress(pyhand, 'PyRun_SimpleString') - pyhand)

print "Py_InitializeEx:    0x{0:08x}".format(py_initialize_ex)
print "PyRun_SimpleString: 0x{0:08x}".format(pyrun_simple_string)

""" Code runs fine with below instruction omitted. """

kernel32.CreateRemoteThread(processh, None, 0, py_initialize_ex, 0, 0, byref(thread_id))#Execute Py_InitializeEx in target process
```

Comment: You're passing around 64-bit pointers truncated as the default 32-bit C `int` values. When you work with functions that return pointers and take pointer arguments you have to declare each function's `restype` and `argtypes`.

Comment: Start with [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17524073/205580) to inject a DLL. Next, don't assume a DLL loads at its preferred base address in the target process. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34593767/205580) for code to get the address of an exported function, taking into account the base-address offset. To do this it creates a Tool-Help snapshot of the target process and walks the loaded modules.

Comment: im working on this among other projects, i will report my progress and accept answers at a later stage, thanks so far :)