# OSError: [WinError 126] module could not be found

Tags: python, dll, ctypes, mxnet

I am trying to run [MXNet port of SSD](https://github.com/zhreshold/mxnet-ssd) in python but I am facing a strange error when I run the demo saying

```
OSError: [WinError 126] The specified module could not be found
```

specifically when trying to open `libmxnet.dll` so I found when I tried to debug it.

the whole error message is like this:

```
>>>> kernel32
>>>>  C:\Users\wisdom\Anaconda3\envs\gpu-test\lib\site-packages\mxnet\libmxnet.dll
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "demo.py", line 2, in <module>
    import tools.find_mxnet
  File "C:\Users\wisdom\Desktop\mxnet-ssd-master\tools\find_mxnet.py", line 6, in <module>
    import mxnet as mx
  File "C:\Users\wisdom\Anaconda3\envs\gpu-test\lib\site-packages\mxnet\__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from .context import Context, current_context, cpu, gpu, cpu_pinned
  File "C:\Users\wisdom\Anaconda3\envs\gpu-test\lib\site-packages\mxnet\context.py", line 24, in <module>
    from .base import classproperty, with_metaclass, _MXClassPropertyMetaClass
  File "C:\Users\wisdom\Anaconda3\envs\gpu-test\lib\site-packages\mxnet\base.py", line 213, in <module>
    _LIB = _load_lib()
  File "C:\Users\wisdom\Anaconda3\envs\gpu-test\lib\site-packages\mxnet\base.py", line 204, in _load_lib
    lib = ctypes.CDLL(lib_path[0], ctypes.RTLD_LOCAL)
  File "C:\Users\wisdom\Anaconda3\envs\gpu-test\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 353, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
OSError: [WinError 126] The specified module could not be found
```

where first two lines with >>>> sign indicate to the lines I was trying to debug and check where/when the error is fired in `...\ctypes\__init__.py` file which look like this

```
if handle is None:
    x = (self._name)
    print('>>>>',x)
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
```

I checked of course the existence of the requested file `libmxnet.dll` and it is there, but whenever it is called it throws this error!

Comment: Take a look at this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17033733/call-to-getmodulehandle-on-kernel32-using-python-c-types), maybe can help you. And look at the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ctypes.html)

Comment: oh I forgot to mention that I tried to replace the code with 'WinDLL(slef._name, use_last_error=True)' but then it falls in recursion throwing 'RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object'!

Comment: That's weird... May you post your complete code? Or just where you define `self._name` and what is  your handle? Thanks

Comment: the code can be found [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/ctypes/__init__.py) and the error usually is being thrown at line 351. if I try to change `_dlopen()` function to `WinDLL()` - which I dont think I should- it will fall in recursion! I tried as well just to open python interpreter and run `WinDLL('...\\libmxnet.dll')` function but still the same error 'module could not be found'

Comment: Well... This is the module source code right? Can you show how are you trying to use? Maybe has sometingh about the `self._name` which is wrong. Did you just put `libmxnet.dll` or the entire path to the dll file? Because I think you should do something like this `"C:\\Windows\\System32\\kernel32.dll"`

Comment: yeah of course I put the full path but still no help! what I am trying to do is just running the code as described in the [repository](https://github.com/zhreshold/mxnet-ssd#try-the-demo) and the [demo code](https://github.com/zhreshold/mxnet-ssd/blob/master/demo.py) could be found there as well.

Comment: Ok my bad about that... I think you shold open an issue there in there into the repo. Because for me don't make any sense this error. Sorry for that. :(

Comment: don't worry...I opened one already ;)

Comment: You're actually expected to first extract a [mcve] from your code and post that as part of your question inline. No volatile external links to your whole project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok finally solved!

I got to know that such error could be thrown when the file dependencies are not satisfied or not found. So to check the dependencies you go first to Visual Studio Prompt and then navigate to the folder where `libmxnet.dll` exists and run the following command

`dumpbin /dependents libmxnet.dll`

and it will show you a list of required files.

What was missing in my case are some of `nVidia GPU Computing Toolkit` files `Cuda 9.0` as `libmxnet.dll` asks for them and I was having toolkit version 10.0 instead!

Comment: What and where the visual studio prompt is?

Comment: @myradio he just meant the windows command prompt...

Answer (score 0):

you should install vcredist_x64 or vcredist_x86 package stands for Visual C++ Redistributable.